# React Component - return from fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

1. Why `this.getAccount()` doesn't return my **json** from **fetch**?.
2. With callback **this.getAccount(function ($) { return $ })** still doesn't work.

## React Component

```jsx
  getAccount () {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.2:3000/account', {
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(function ($) {
      return $.json()
    }).then(function ($) {
      return $
    })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.getAccount()
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: `getAccount` returns `undefined` in your code because there is no return from `getAccount` -  once you fix that, then the only thing it can return is a Promise,  it can not return an asynchronous value synchronously

Comment: @JaromandaX So it's impossible to do?

Comment: I didn't say that - see the question this is marked as a duplicate of